# How to run "make" from a higher-level directory?

Tags: bash, terminal

Let's say I'm in a subdirectory `sub`:

```
admin@pc ~/folder/subfolder $
```

I would like to run `make` on a `Makefile` from the `folder` directory.

How can I achieve it when I'm in the `subfolder` directory?

I had some ideas like:

```
admin@pc ~/folder/subfolder $ ../make
admin@pc ~/folder/subfolder $ /../make
```

but none of these works.

Comment: For GNU make: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options-Summary ( -C )

Comment: Do you need to run make in the current directory but with a makefile that lives in a different directory or you do need to change to that other directory and run make from there (but want to do that without manually using `cd`)?

Comment: I have to stay in the current directory. And yes, I wanted to avoid using `cd` two times: `$ cd .. && make && cd subfolder`. One way or another - the problem has been already solved.

Comment: The given solutions are all very different. Specifically the chosen solution doesn't run make from the other directory. It runs make from the current directory.

Comment: What I was trying to achieve was: 1. running `make` in the `folder`. 2. copying a compiled `program` to `subfolder` using `cp ../program .`. 3. running a bash script which tests `program`. The point was that the mentioned script had to be run from the `subfolder` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative, built-in answer, that avoids the extra sub-shell from khachik's answer is the answer given by helpYou in their comment:

To run make from a different directory automatically you want the [`-C` option to make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options-Summary).

> ‘-C dir’
>
> ‘--directory=dir’
>
> Change to directory dir before reading the makefiles. If multiple ‘-C’ options are specified, each is interpreted relative to the previous one: ‘-C / -C etc’ is equivalent to ‘-C /etc’. This is typically used with recursive invocations of make (see Recursive Use of make).

The `-f` argument simply specifies an alternate makefile to use but runs in the current directory.

The sub-shell solution is a good one and would be the correct one if make did not have a built-in solution for this.

Answer (score 3):

And if for some reason you really need to run `make` in `..`, you can run

```
(cd .. && make)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer.

```
make -C .. -f Makefile
```